# fail2ban adding PHP Function

Tags: mysql, debian, iptables, fail2ban

fail2ban has to add the banned IP, TIME and which protocol was used before banning in mysql.

I used the following manual: 
https://de.saas-secure.com/online-services/fail2ban-ip-weiterleiten.html

But I get some troubles until the point where I have to setup the iptables-multiport.conf

I added the actionban where is written in the manual. If I delete the actionban, everything is working fine.

I also tried to write the actionban in the actually format but nothing happen.
I don't know where the problem is.

Here my actionban:

```
actionban = <iptables> -I f2b-<name> 1 -s <ip> -j <blocktype> DROP /opt/fail2ban.php <name> <protocol> <port> <ip>
```

I can restart the fail2ban process but nothing happens if I try to login with wrong data.

I already tried the php-Data in /opt/ with ./fail2ban.php it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

A [jail can have multiple actions](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/d65d7fd4d02bc7d713d362591a8d67aa6f4aa668/man/jail.conf.5#L289). So create a new action for the PHP script and add this to the actions for the jail(s) of interest.

PS. Don't consider `addslashes` a reliable SQL injection prevention mechanism